# YouTube Event Broadcast Status of testing does not allow new stream binding

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

So when you test streaming to an event (via the RTMP endpoint) you switch the events `lifeCycleStatus` to `testing`. When I stop streaming to the RTMP endpoint the `lifeCycleStatus` still remains `testing`.

Essentially I need the event to go from this `testing` state to one where I can create and bind a new live stream to the event.

An attempt to transition the broadcast status of the event to `Live` is met with the error that the stream status is currently `inactive` which makes sense.

Is it possible to transition an event in the `testing` state to one where I can bind a new stream to it?

Comment: I think it is possible as it stated [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#status.lifeCycleStatus). If the value of `status.lifeCycleStatus` is in the **`ready`** state `The broadcast settings are complete and the broadcast can transition to a live or testing status.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to solve this issue. Just to let you know there is no way to move a `LiveBroadcast` from the `lifeCycleStatus` from `TESTING` to anything other than `LIVE` or `COMPLETED`.

You can however rebind a new `LiveStream` to a `LiveBroadcast` in the state of `TESTING`. The broadcast will have a new `boundStream` and the `lifeCycleStatus` will be `CREATED`